# NSUserDefaults with suit name swift

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, keyboard, custom-keyboard

I have created a custom keyboard for ios using swift and i need to add a settings page so i have try to pass data between container application and keyboard application i have added the `AppGroups` in AppGroup and this is the code i have used

in container app view controller

`var defaults: NSUserDefaults = NSUserDefaults(suiteName: "group.xxxxx")!
 defaults.setObject("t1", forKey: "theme")`

and in `UIInputViewController` class

`var defaults: NSUserDefaults = NSUserDefaults(suiteName: "group.xxxxx")!
 var test = defaults.stringForKey("theme")`

but for `test` i am always getting null
can somebody tell me what i have done wrong i am using swift language or there is a another way to create a settings view for custom keyboards

Answer (score 1):

[From Documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/General/Conceptual/ExtensibilityPG/ExtensionScenarios.html)

> ....
>
> To enable data sharing, use Xcode or the Developer portal to enable
>   app groups for the containing app and its contained app extensions.
>   Next, register the app group in the portal and specify the app group
>   to use in the containing app. To learn about working with app groups,
>   see Adding an App to an App Group.  ....

I think in your case, this is not set up properly?

Comment: using  x-code i have accepted the agreement , do i need to register the app group i have created in developer portal too ? i have checked my developer portal and my group is there on app group